# Run gradle task after doLast of a other task

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a variable in my build.gradle (***xy***) file with an integer value and three simple tasks. The tree tasks are also "bundled" in a fourth task, to call the three tasks one after one. If I call the task ***callAll***, the task ***callOne*** should add 5 to the int value, task ***callTwo*** should add also 5 the int value, but in a doLast block and finally task ***callThree*** prints out the value. It should be 10 but it prints 5, I guess because of the doLast block. But I dont understand why, I declared to call task ***callThree*** it mustRunAfter ***callTwo*** in the task ***callAll***.

This example is of course a simplified version of a more complex build.gradle I have. How can i get the right output, without changing the three simple tasks?

```
project.ext{
 xy= 0
}

task callOne(){
 xy = xy + 5
}

task callTwo(){
 doLast{
  xy = xy + 5
 } 
}

task callThree(){
 println "xy : $xy"
}

task callAll(){
 dependsOn 'callOne'
 dependsOn 'callTwo'
 dependsOn 'callThree'

 tasks.findByName('callTwo').mustRunAfter 'callOne'
 tasks.findByName('callThree').mustRunAfter 'callTwo'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Gradle build runs three distinct phases: Initialization, Configuration and Execution ([Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases)).

In the configuration phase, the project and its tasks are configured. During this phase:

- `callOne` sets `xy = xy + 5`
- `callTwo` does nothing
- `callThree` prints `println "xy : $xy"`

Tasks are executed in the execution phase of the Gradle build, this means:

- `callOne` does nothing
- `callTwo` sets `xy = xy + 5`
- `callThree` does nothing

`5` is printed rather than `10` since you're mixing configuration and execution phases.

`callAll` is more or less only a custom lifecycle task that configures the task graph. In itself, `callAll` performs no calls to the other tasks and consequently does nothing in the execution phase.

You may get your desired behavior by enclosing all task actions in a `doFirst {}` or `doLast {}` block.

Please have a look at [Configuration time and execution time](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_configuration_and_execution.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, so callThree does nothing in the execution phase? Very interesting, apparently I have to take a closer look at phases again. I thought the call in ***callAll*** would explicitly start it again

Comment: Yes, `callOne` and `callThree` do not have an action and thus do nothing in the execution phase. `callAll` is more or less only a custom lifecycle task, has no action and just wires up the task graph. In itself, `callAll` performs no calls to the other tasks.